# is inner product space a formalization of the intuitive understanding of vectors as "arrows"?

Tags: linear-algebra

as I have read, inner product space is a generalization of R2 and R3 Euclidean vector spaces. is the in the sense of formalizing the intuitive understanding of vectors as "arrows"?

Comment: A [Euclidean vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) is a finite-dimensional inner product space over the real numbers. So this is already an inner product space and generalizes of course $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$, see the wikipedia article for the "understanding of vectors".

Comment: Vector spaces are quite general and do not need to rely on "arrows" to understand.  Inner product spaces are just as general.  The only thing that inner product spaces do that arbitrary vector spaces do not is to include the concept of an inner product, a way of taking a product of two elements in such a way that it returns a scalar.  An example of an inner product space would be the set of real continuous functions over the domain $[0,1]$, often denoted as $C([0,1])$, and the inner product being $\langle f,g\rangle = \int\limits_{0}^1f(x)g(x)dx$.  Good luck visualizing "arrows" here...

Comment: I would say that an inner product gives you a generalized notion of “angle” between vectors. In a sense, this gives vectors a direction, like arrows

Comment: As mentioned above, there are infinite dimensional inner product spaces. But I'd say that **Euclidean Vector Spaces** (as defined by @DietrichBurde) which are special inner product spaces formalize our understanding of arrows.

Comment: Inner products came out of trying to isolate Fourier coefficients in a trigonometric expansion of the initial displacement of a thin vibrating wire. Finite-dimensional inner products came later.

Answer (score 0):

A normed space is enough to formalize the intuition of vectors as arrows with a "direction" and "magnitude". The intuition is that any nonzero vector is formed by first picking a unit vector (the direction), and then picking the length of the vector.

Formally, suppose $V$ is a normed vector space. Let $S = \{\omega \in V : \|\omega\| = 1\}$. The arrow intuition is based on the polar coordinates map $f :  S \times (0, \infty) \to V \setminus \{0\}$ given by $f(\omega, r) = r\omega$. The inverse of this map is $f^{-1}(v) = (\frac{v}{\|v\|}, \|v\|)$.

Comment: Yes, but it is not enough to define angles.